# How can I show different files one under the other when selecting a file?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<div class="selected-file-container align-items-center justify-content-between d-none">
  <div class="selected-file d-flex align-items-center">
     <img id="selectedImage" class="hidden" src="" alt="Selected Image"/>
     <span id="selectedFileName">Filename.jpg</span>
  </div>
  <span>1 MB</span>
</div>
<input type="file" id="fileInput" style="display: none" />
<label for="fileInput" class="choose-file-btn">
  <span>Choose File</span>
</label>
```

Here, I designed an image selection button with HTML and Bootstrap and an area where an icon can be placed next to the name of the selected image.

```
<script>
  document.getElementById("fileInput").addEventListener("change", function (event) {
    const selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
    const selectedImageElement = document.getElementById("selectedImage");
    const selectedFileNameElement = document.getElementById("selectedFileName");
    const selectedFileContainer = document.querySelector(".selected-file-container");
    if (selectedFile) {
      const imageIconElement = document.createElement("i");
      imageIconElement.className = "fa-regular fa-image";
      selectedFileNameElement.innerHTML = "";
      selectedFileNameElement.appendChild(imageIconElement);
      selectedFileNameElement.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", selectedFile.name);
      selectedImageElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(selectedFile);
      selectedFileContainer.classList.remove("d-none");
      selectedFileContainer.classList.add("d-flex");
    } else {
        // Dosya seçilmediyse selected-file-container'ı gizle
        selectedFileContainer.classList.remove("d-flex");
        selectedFileContainer.classList.add("d-none");
      }
  });
</script>
```

Here is my script code, in which I select an image with the script and when the image is selected, I add an image icon to the `selectedFileContainer` and just the name of the selected image (I do not show the image, I use an icon instead).

What I'm trying to do and what I can't do is this: Let's say the user selected an image, let it be x.jpg. In the container containing the `selectedFileContainer` class, there is an icon and the name of the selected image next to it. When the user selects a second image, let's say it is `y.jpg`. It overwrites the name `x.jpg`. What I am trying to do is to list the `selectedFileContainer` one under the other every time the user adds a new image. Whatever was selected last goes to the bottom. Let them line up in blocks, above the button.

[image]

[image]

When different images are selected, only the name changes within the same container, as seen in the image. Instead, create selected-file-containers with the name of the selected image one under the other.

Comment: Why not have a `.parent-container` where you  append the `selected-file-container` every time the user selects a new image?

that way you can easier manage what is inserted and what is not - as it sounds like you overwritting now?

Comment: Just like you create that `i` element, you can create whole section instead with icon, image name and additional info and append/prepend that in `selected-file-container` div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create a separate container for each of the files

```js
document.getElementById("fileInput").addEventListener("change", function (event) {
    const files = event.target.files;
    const filesContainer = document.getElementById("filesContainer");

    for (const file of files) {

        const fileContainer = document.createElement("div");
        fileContainer.className = "selected-file-container align-items-center justify-content-between d-flex";

        const fileDisplay = document.createElement("div");
        fileDisplay.className = "selected-file d-flex align-items-center";

        const imageIconElement = document.createElement("i");
        imageIconElement.className = "fa-regular fa-image";

        const fileNameElement = document.createElement("span");
        fileNameElement.textContent = file.name;

        fileDisplay.appendChild(imageIconElement);
        fileDisplay.appendChild(fileNameElement);
        fileContainer.appendChild(fileDisplay);


        filesContainer.appendChild(fileContainer);
    }


    event.target.value = '';
});
```

```html
<div id="filesContainer"></div>

<input type="file" id="fileInput" style="display: none" multiple />
<label for="fileInput" class="choose-file-btn">
    <span>Choose File</span>
</label>
```

Comment: Yes I got it and it worked. However, the text 1 MB, which should be on the far right side as span, disappeared.

Comment: After filesContainer  just add <span>1MB</span>

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution would be to wrap your `.selected-file-container` in a template tag, and then clone it, add the relevant file data to it before appending it to a container.

```js
const displaySelectedFiles = (event) => {
  const files = event.target.files;
  const container = document.getElementById("file-container");
  const template = document.getElementById("file");
  
  for (file of files) {
    const fileTemplate = template.content.cloneNode(true);
    
    fileTemplate.getElementById("selectedImage").src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
    fileTemplate.getElementById("selectedFileName").textContent = file.name;
  
    container.appendChild(fileTemplate);
  }
}

document.getElementById("fileInput").addEventListener("change", displaySelectedFiles);
```

```css
.choose-file-btn {
  cursor: pointer;
}

img {
  height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<template id="file">
 <div class="selected-file-container align-items-center justify-content-between d-none">
    <div class="selected-file d-flex align-items-center">
       <img id="selectedImage" class="hidden" src="" alt="Selected Image"/>
       <span id="selectedFileName">Filename.jpg</span>
    </div>
    <span>1 MB</span>
  </div>
</template>

<input type="file" id="fileInput" multiple style="display: none" />
<label for="fileInput" class="choose-file-btn">
  <span>Choose File</span>
</label>

<div id="file-container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So if you want to add more than 1 image you should remove `<img>` from HTML, because every new image will change the `src` of the `img` in HTML.
So every time when you add an image you should create a new element `<img>`. There is correct JS and HTML code:

JS

```
document
.getElementById("fileInput")
.addEventListener("change", function (event) {
    const selectedFile = event.target.files[0];

    const selectedImageElement =
        document.getElementById("selectedImage");
    const selectedFileNameElement =
        document.getElementById("selectedFileName");
    const selectedFileContainer = document.querySelector(
        ".selected-file-container"
    );

    if (selectedFile) {
        const imageIconElement = document.createElement("i");
        const image = document.createElement("img");
        image.innerHTML = `<img
            id="selectedImage"
            class="hidden"
            src=""
            alt="Selected Image"
        />`
        image.src = URL.createObjectURL(selectedFile);
        
        imageIconElement.className = "fa-regular fa-image";
    
        selectedFileNameElement.appendChild(image);
        selectedFileNameElement.insertAdjacentHTML(
            "beforeend",
            selectedFile.name
        );

        selectedImageElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(selectedFile);
        selectedFileContainer.classList.add("d-flex");
    } else {
        // Dosya seçilmediyse selected-file-container'ı gizle
        selectedFileContainer.classList.add("d-none");
    }
});
```

HTML

```
<div class="selected-file-container align-items-center justify-content-between d-none">
    <div class="selected-file d-flex align-items-center">
        <span id="selectedFileName">Filename.jpg</span>
    </div>
    <span>1 MB</span>
</div>
<input type="file" id="fileInput" style="display: none" />
<label for="fileInput" class="choose-file-btn">
    <span>Choose File</span>
</label>
```

Comment: PS: If you want the images and the names of the images use my code, however if you want only the names without the images use @Hezy Ziv code.